# Windows 10 - Can ping IP but cannot ping hostname on my LAN

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, ping

I tried searching for my answer on Google and then Stack Overflow but clearly I am not using the right keywords.

Problem: I have two Windows 10 laptops on my LAN, both wireless connections if that matters. The laptop named `main` seems to have forgotten the laptop named `spare`. Two days ago "ping spare" worked. Today `main` cannot ping (or tracert) `spare`. I powered down `main` between the two sessions.

Additional clue: main could not ping the IP of spare until I had spare ping main and **then** main knew how to ping the IP of spare.

Does anyone out there recognize this situation and can help a programmer who's in over his head with networking details?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try disable the **firewall**, **antivirus** and all others apps with similar function.
2. Look at **Device Manager** by run the cmd **devmgmt.msc** and check out if all drivers are ok, mainly the NIC's.
3. Try **ping** and **tracert** each other (From MAIN to SPARE and opposite) and check out if there are some packet loss.
4. Post here the **ping** and **tracert** cmd output of either machines
5. Post here the **ipconfig /all** cmd output of either machines.

References:

- [Device Manager](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-device-manager-2626075)
- [ipconfig](https://www.lifewire.com/ip-config-818377/windows-commands/ipconfig)

Comment: I looked at the drivers - nothing but "working properly" there - on either machine.
And as for pinging - same actions as before - Spare can ping Main by name and IP - but Main can only ping Spare by IP.....I wish I understood the networking side of this a little more than I do. I feel strongly this is something to do with DNS in some fashion

Comment: I came across this page [link]https://www.lifewire.com/fix-ipv6-no-network-access-error-4684594 where I found its Step #6 resolved my issues...Although I still need to give my computer the acid test of powering down and seeing if the correction holds